# Floating Divs resizing after moving

Tags: css, html, width

I have a DIV.  Inside it I have two floating DIV's.
One floats left and one floats right.

The one which floats left has a width of calc(100%-284px).
The one which floats right has a width of 284px.
They are both inside a DIV which is a center popup with a width of 70%.

```
   -----------------------
   |   Main Div 70%      |
15%|---------- ----------|15%
   || float  | |  float ||
   || left   | |  right ||
   |---------- ----------|
   -----------------------
```

When I resize my window the 70% shrinks which is good.
To prevent the left float being squished, it has a min-width of 284px.

I carry on shrinking my screen, the right float drops below the left float.
It looks awful now as I have one column and two rows (one slightly left and one slightly right)
and the one slightly left has a big gap of 284px next to it.

```
--------------------
| -----------      |
| | left    |  284 |
| | float   |  gap |
| -----------      |
|  ?     ----------|
|  gap   |  right ||
|        |        ||
|        ----------|
--------------------
```

Ideally I would like my left float to change size from calc(100%-284) to 100%.
The right float which is now underneath it.

```
--------------------
|------------------|
| left      |
|------------------|
|   -----------    |
|   |  right  |    |
|   -----------    |
--------------------
```

Please can someone show me the code how to do this, I imagine its easy enough but I can't see it.

```
#Left{
        display: block;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        float: left;
        width: -webkit-calc(100% - 284px); 
        width: -moz-calc(100% - 284px);
        width: calc(100% - 284px);
        min-width: 284px;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: 6px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
    }

    #Right{
        float: right;
        width: 250px;
        height: auto;
        margin-right: 6px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
            }

     #Popup {
        font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        color: #333333;
        display: none;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-left: 15%;
        margin-right: 15%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 15%;
        bottom: 15%;
        width: 70%;
        z-index: 222;
        text-align: center;
}
```

Thank you Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of layout your making but,
You could use css media queries. The right div will drop when it reaches 250px;

http://jsfiddle.net/3VPYd/

```
@media all and (max-width: 732px) {
     #left {
        background: green;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #right {
        background: pink;
        float: none;
        margin: auto;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: I use media queries for my boiler plate, I didn't think about using them for a popup div.  Thank you for doing the jsfiddle